# Can we change the [studies] tag to [scientific-research]?

Tags: discussion

Honestly, [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies) seems a bit open-ended. This could relate to schoolwork or studying a language, rather than scientific documentation on the subject. On the other hand, [scientific-research](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-research) is clear, direct, and can't be misinterpreted.